# LibGDX: poor quality when rendering in Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How can you solve the problem of poor quality when rendering everything, for which these pixels are in the screenshot made by the device (not using libgdx), it looks like dithering, while on the desktop there is no such thing.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I still found the answer to my question, you need to set all R G B A channels to 8

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.useImmersiveMode = true;
    config.numSamples = 2;
    config.r = 8;
    config.g = 8;
    config.b = 8;
    config.a = 8;
    opener = new AndroidGalleryOpener(this);
    initialize(new Start(opener), config);
}
```

Comment: 8880 is default on Android for 1.9.13, maybe just update to the latest libgdx release